# Log4j2 - Stackoverflow at AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy using programmatically configuration

Tags: java, spring, log4j2

my current project have a need to update the log4j2 configuration using properties from the Spring context. To achieve this I've done a listener that reloads log4j2 context when the spring context is loaded (on an EnvironmentChangeEvent). The listener works correctly and the first time the context is loaded with my configuration. But when a refresh is done, via an /refresh endpoint in this case, the application throws an Stackoverflow error in AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy of log4j2.

The error ocurrs in this two lines:

```
result = next.get();
return result.getReliabilityStrategy().getActiveLoggerConfig(next);
```

The error is not related with Spring Boot because I've done a junit test that replicates the error with only Log4j2 classes:

```
@Test
public void testAwaitCompletionStackOverflow() {
    Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(this.getClass());
    final LoggerContext ctx = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
    final Configuration config = ctx.getConfiguration();
    PatternLayout layout = PatternLayout.createLayout(PatternLayout.SIMPLE_CONVERSION_PATTERN, null, config, null,
        null,false, false, null, null);
    Appender appender = FileAppender.createAppender("target/test.log", "false", "false", "File", "true",
        "false", "false", "4000", layout, null, "false", null, config);
    appender.start();
    config.addAppender(appender);
    AppenderRef ref = AppenderRef.createAppenderRef("File", null, null);
    AppenderRef[] refs = new AppenderRef[] {ref};
    LoggerConfig loggerConfig = LoggerConfig.createLogger("false", Level.INFO, "testlog4j2refresh",
        "true", refs, null, config, null );
    loggerConfig.addAppender(appender, null, null);
    config.addLogger("testlog4j2refresh", loggerConfig);
    ctx.stop();
    ctx.start(config);

    log.error("Info message");
}
```

I've filled an issue at log4j2 JIRA https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-2134 but in the meantime must look for a solution or workaround for this problem.

Actually my solution was been creating a little patch that checks at AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy if the "next" result is equals to the actual result and return actual result in that case but I think is not ok to deploy an microservice in production with a patched log4j2 library.

Are there any other way to solve this? Or is any other way to load the configuration of log4j programmatically?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug was succesfully fixed:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-2134?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel&focusedCommentId=16656285#comment-16656285